# Selecting MySQL session variables multiple times

Tags: mysql, session, variables, procedures

Having a weird problem selecting session variables which are changed by a stored procedure.

```
 call calculate("input1", "input2",@price);
 select @price; /*price is 2.00*/


 call calculate("anotherinput","anotherinput2",@price);
 select @price; /*price is 3.00*/
```

However, the answer I get is actually 2 3.00's rather than the 2.00 then the 3.00. Assuming it's getting overwritten and messing it all up. But what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Post the contents of the stored procedure

Comment: has an INOUT of fare and a @price set above it

Answer (score 0):

Procedure might have not defined the parameter `price` as an `OUT` parameter, but `IN` parameter. Unless which the passed `IN` parameter will always show the same OLD passed value.

**Working Example**:

```
mysql> create procedure test_sp( inout p int, in q int ) set p := p*q;
mysql> set @p := 4; set @q := 6;
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> call test_sp( @p, @q );
    -> select @p, @q;
    -> call test_sp( @p, @q );
    -> select @p, @q;
    -> //

+------+------+
| @p   | @q   |
+------+------+
|   24 |    6 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+------+
| @p   | @q   |
+------+------+
|  144 |    6 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: I'm actually using INOUT just like your example, strange.

Comment: Can you post signature of SP. `procedure sp_name( in... )`

Comment: And in one of the comments on your posting, you said `inout` was on `fare`. What about `price`? You better post the SP's signature.

Comment: SET @cost = 00.00;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS calculate;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE calculate
(
 IN input1 VARCHAR(128),
 IN input2 VARCHAR(128),
 INOUT fare DECIMAL (30,2)
)

Comment: Perhaps you are not resetting the fare value in the SP body. Check it.

Comment: May be on a condition skip on other parameters, fare was un-altered.

Comment: as in i should do set fare = 0 in the SP? edit - doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: is it because my input1 and inpit2 for example is how i'm calculating the price and they are just IN rather than INOUT? getting errors now with INOUT though

Comment: i'm not setting @fare in the SP, just fare. but this also doesnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: Can you post your SP body, so it would be mush easier to figure out what is wrong with.